# How to escape? data that is being inserted into sqlite database.

Tags: sqlite, cordova

I'm making an apple app using phone gap (which uses sqlite database).

All my inserts work fine except for when I try to insert a weblink. This errors because there are " characters in the weblink.

Using the following:

```
var content = 'hello, this is my <a href="www.google.com">link</a>'
tx.executeSql('UPDATE PAGES SET content="'+content+'" WHERE id="1"');
```

Brings back the following error

```
error code 1
error: "near "http": syntax error"
```

If I remove the website address, I don't get an error. I have tried:
    content = escape(content);

but that hasn't worked.

Comment: There is no "http" in this code, which means the error is somewhere else.

Comment: That's my fault, there is http in the my real version. I just typed that out quickly. Sorry.

Answer (score 11):

Use parameter binding. This is the right and the safest way to do what you're trying to do.

```
tx.executeSql('UPDATE PAGES SET content=? WHERE id=1', [content]);
```

Answer (score 4):

To escape quotes in SQLite you'll have to *repeat* the quotes.

So to insert `a 7" screen`  you'll have to put `a 7"" screen` in the INSERT statement.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the quote marks. They change the meaning of the SQL request and cause the error.

I can't find any information on escaping them properly. I read that you can put \ before them and then add ESCAPE ("\") to the SQL statement, but this doesn't seem to work with PhoneGap's implementation.

In the end, I did a simple replace, where single or double quote marks are replaced with `&quot;`, like so:

```
var thisNotes = $('textarea#notes').val().replace(/(["'])/g,'&quot;');
```

I just need to display quote marks in a text field however - I don't need them as part of a HTML link, so I'm not sure whether the link would still work. You may need to reverse the replace before displaying the link.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Then again, it seems a double quote mark may be a better answer, as per this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603572/how-to-properly-escape-a-single-quote-for-a-sqlite-database)

Comment: So I've now revised my code to use .replace(/"/g,'""'). The single quotes seem to be fine, it's just the double ones and the above code fixes that.

Answer (score 0):

use javascript replace   maybe create a function like so:

```
function CleanDbData( dirty ){
     var clean = dirty.replace( "/"","''").replace("<script>","[script]");
     return clean;
}

var mydata = CleanDbData( dirtydata );
```

this is not AS is, you will have to mess with regex etc but you get the idea [hopefully]