# javascript: create SQlite statement with escaped double quotes

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

I am trying to escape the double quotation marks in my json string in order to execute the following sqlite statement in phonegap ie. using javascript:

> var sqlstatement= 'INSERT INTO ACTIVITY(activity)
>   VALUES("{\"clicks\":100, \"activityTypeCode\":3}")'

However when It try:

```
tx.executeSql(sqlStatement,errorCB, sucessCB)
```

the double quotes arent escaped and I go to the errorCallback because of the many pairs of double quotes. is there a way around this?

Comment: This is a duplicate of "How to escape? data that is being inserted into sqlite database." See following:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7608378/how-to-escape-data-that-is-being-inserted-into-sqlite-database

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a parameterised statement:

```
tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO ACTIVITY (clicks, activityTypeCode) VALUES (?, ?)",
              [activity.clicks, activity.activityTypeCode], successCB, errorCB);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to store a JSON string it seems, you need a different syntax.

```
 var insertStatement = "INSERT INTO ACTIVITY (clicks, activityTypeCode) VALUES (100, 3)";
```

This page might help you with the rest of it:

http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Store_data_in_the_HTML5_SQLite_database-19115.html