# How to insert double quote ( " ) into SQLite Database Varchar field?

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, double-quotes

I'm trying to insert into a table with this field `TITLE varchar(200) NOT NULL` the next sentence:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO EXAMPLETABLE VALUES ("1-Preludi \"Obrint Pas 2011\"", ...
```

The problem is that SQLite missunderstand the \" escape caracter , and i don't know how to put it to resolve the problem (Maybe a character code?) in my Android program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To insert values into a database you should always use [SQLiteStatement](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteStatement.html) ([HowTo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433392/how-do-i-use-prepared-statements-in-sqlite-in-android)) as they escape your values and prevent your app from being targeted with [SQL-Injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Also, if you're inserting multiple values (say in a loop), executing a precompiled statement with different bound values is much faster than a normal insert-statement.

Comment: Actually, you should use the SQLite interface supplied especially by Android and pass the values as ContentValues instead, using (for instance) the SQLiteDatabase#insert(String, String, ContentValues) method.

Comment: @Jens You're right, in Android the insert-params are escaped. But most of the people only supply the raw-query and leave the params with `Null`. That's why I suggest a normal PreparedStatement.

Comment: Ah, you are referring to using SQLiteStatement:s, not actual standard Java PreparedStatements.

Comment: @Jens yep, I was going to, but I got the wrong class from the docs. My mistake.

Answer (score 17):

Just working with sqlite and direct sql insert commands from the command line, I find that double quoting escapes itself.
With your example

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO EXAMPLETABLE VALUES ("1-Preludi ""Obrint Pas 2011""", ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something similar:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("YOURCOLUMNNAME", "1-Preludi \"Obrint Pas 2011\"");
// ... other stuff you want to insert ...
SQLiteDatabase db = ... ; // Usually obtained using a SQLiteOpenHelper
long id = db.insertWithOnConflict("EXAMPLETABLE", BaseColumns._ID, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use This To Insert Data with any special charecter

```
ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
initialValues.put("Id", id);
initialValues.put("Name", Name);
// ...
myDataBase.insert("EXAMPLETABLE", null, initialValues);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO EXAMPLETABLE VALUES ('1-Preludi "Obrint Pas 2011"', ...
```

Comment: +1 I've tried but i have problems with ' :D , then this solution doesn't run but its easy one if you only have problems with " .

Comment: If your inputs have mixed single/double quotes, this will break.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `''` to surround the value, then between `''`, you can use double quotes without escaped as shown below so '1-Preludi "Obrint Pas 2011"' is evaluated to `1-Preludi "Obrint Pas 2011"`. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603572/escape-single-quote-character-for-use-in-an-sqlite-query/77212862#77212862) explains it more:

```
                                           ↓                           ↓
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO EXAMPLETABLE VALUES ('1-Preludi "Obrint Pas 2011"', ...
```

In addition, you cannot use double quotes to surround the value as shown below because there is error:

```
                                           ↓                             ↓
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO EXAMPLETABLE VALUES ("1-Preludi ""Obrint Pas 2011""", ...
```