# How to fix `no such table` error with SQLite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, xcode4, dbtable

I had to search for many posts regarding these errors, but still I cannot fix the problem. Here is my code, can anyone help me to see what is going wrong?

```
- (void) copyDatabaseIfNeeded {


    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
   NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SQL.sqlite"];

    if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &newDBconnection) == SQLITE_OK) 
    {
        NSLog(@"Database opened successfully");

if(updateStmt == nil) {
            NSString *updStmt = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"UPDATE Coffee SET CoffeeName = '500 Plus', Price = '1.40' Where CoffeeID= '3'"];
   const char *mupdate_stmt = [updStmt UTF8String]; 

if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(newDBconnection, mupdate_stmt, -1, &updateStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK){
NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating update statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(newDBconnection));
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Update successful");
            }

        }
        if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(updateStmt))
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while updating. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(newDBconnection));
        else {
            sqlite3_reset(updateStmt);
            NSLog(@"Step successful");

        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        NSLog(@"Error in opening database  ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

There is no table `Coffee` in `SQL.sqlite`.

SQLite silently creates the database file if it does not exist. So if you've got the `path` wrong, you are opening *an empty database file*, which of course does not contain any tables. Make sure the database file exists there and it is not empty.

You can see what tables are there in the database by running `SELECT * FROM sqlite_master;` query.

Comment: I can find the Coffee table by executing the SQL "SELECT * FROM sqlite_master", and the database is opened successfully, just when it comes to update, the error occur

Comment: @Sunny If you're checking it with SQLite browser or command-line tool, you may be opening different file. Dump `path` into log and query `sqlite_master` by the same code right before doing the `UPDATE`.

Comment: You can also use the `.tables` option in the SQLite command line tool to show the name of every table inside the database.

Comment: Hi @hamstergene I have this problem recently, I am totally new to Xcode, so I tried to running "SELECT * FROM sqlite_master" by using this code:

Comment: @hamstergene `string debug = "SELECT * FROM formalData;";
    debugsql = &debug[0u];
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
    if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
        fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
        sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
    }else{
        fprintf(stdout, "Records created successfully\n");
    }`

Comment: @hamstergene but it doesn't give me the result after running this command in the console below. So my question is... how can I see the result...? It's really a dumb question hahaha, thx!

Answer (score 3):

One thing my DBA tells me when I have database problems (Oracle in this case), is to try the query using the command line tools.

This is how you would diagnose problems with sqlite3 and the iPhone simulator:

1. Run the App in the iPhone Simulator so the database is created/copied in the Documents directory.
2. Start Terminal
3. `cd ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/<version>/Applications/<your-app-hash>/Documents`. It's best to have just one App installed in the simulator so it's obvious what App is what.
4. `sqlite3 SQL.sqlite` and try your query from there.  You can also use the `.schema` command to see what the schema looks like.

If the query works there and not in your App then you know you have a bug, else you have a sqlite query problem or broken schema.

Comment: Strange but, from the command line my query is working but from Objective-C it isn't. I just added new table and this bug occurs. I even have a situation when it works sometimes and suddenly it's broken.

Answer (score 1):

try reinstalling the app.the tables are created at the time of installing the app.sometimes it might happen because tables are not created

Answer (score 0):

I've had a "no such table error" because the db file was never copied to the bin folder.
One the .db file in the project make sure its property "Copy to Output Directory" is set to either:

- Copy always (always copies the blank database)
- Copy if newer

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> Parse error: no such table: public.user

When I tried to rename the table name `public.user` to `user` as shown below. *The table name with `.` happened to me when converting a PostgreSQL dump file to a SQLite dump file with [RebaseData](https://www.rebasedata.com/convert-postgresql-to-sqlite-online):

```sql
ALTER TABLE public.user RENAME TO user;
```

So, I used `""` for `public.user` as shown below, then I could rename the table name without error. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603572/escape-single-quote-character-for-use-in-an-sqlite-query/77212862#77212862) explains it more:

```sql
            ↓           ↓
ALTER TABLE "public.user" RENAME TO user;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error but I could not see anything wrong. I figured out that my issue was in copying the CREATE TABLE from another terminal. I decided to delete the .db files and typed the syntax in by hand. No copy and paste. It stopped giving me the error after that. I can't see any special or hidden characters in the copied syntax, but doing it so was giving me that error every time until I typed it in by hand.