# Why does this sqlite3 command work interactively but not in batch?

Tags: bash, sqlite

I'd like to create a batch script to remove all the records from my db.

If I start up the command line interface, I have no problems:

```
[tomcat@scsrv26v pycsw]$ sqlite3 /var/www/pycsw/tests/suites/cite/data/records.db
SQLite version 3.6.20
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> delete from records;
sqlite> .quit
```

but if I try to run this from batch, it doesn't work:

```
#!/bin/bash
sqlite3 -batch /var/www/pycsw/tests/suites/cite/data/records.db <<"EOF"
delete from records;
.quit
EOF
```

Here's the error I get:

```
Error: near line 1: no such table: records
```

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: I'm not an sqllite user, but I would guess that you need the equivalent of `use correctTableSpace;` before the `delete` command. Good luck.

Comment: Works for me with a file in `/tmp`.  Are you able to create a minimal demonstrable example that we can use?

Comment: Are you running the batch file as the same user on the same machine?

Comment: Yes, I am running both as the same user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the first time I see the indicated syntax. Sorry, I have no idea of how it works.

But this can be solved with ((i use this in windows batch files and as far as i know also in linux):

Command directly from command line

```
sqlite3 records.db 'delete from records'
```

Command piped to sqlite

```
echo delete from records; | sqlite3 records.db
```

And, of course, you can place the commands in a file and redirect into sqlite

```
sqlite3 records.db < myCommands.sql
```

Comment: @IngoBürk, no, as indicated it is the first time i see this command line syntax. But as it seems interesting, while I try to find the reason (and try a new syntax), I posted a workaround for the problem. Is this not acceptable?

Comment: But a workaround is not what was asked for. OP showed very clearly that they *can* get it to work via CLI.

Comment: @IngoBürk, OP showed the operation works from an interactive sqlite prompt. The OP attempts to make it work in batch mode fails. The code I have posted deals with the batch mode and can be used as an alternative solution or additional test while detecting where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Might be something with the path of the .db file argument (see [No Such Table error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103244/no-such-table-error)).  If the .db doesn't exist, it is created with as an empty db file.

To test, see if this works:

```
#!/bin/bash
sqlite3 -batch tests/suites/cite/data/records.db <<"EOF"
select count(*) from records;
.quit
EOF
```

Having said this, this worked for me:

```
$ sqlite3 --version
3.8.7.1 2014-10-29 13:59:56 3b7b72c4685aa5cf5e675c2c47ebec10d9704221
$ sqlite3 tests/suites/cite/data/records.db "delete from records"
```

Comment: The bash script you propose gave me the same error.   I'm going to use the one-liner that MC ND proposed (and that you confirmed!) since it solves my problem.