# Operational error while using stripe with profile app

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-templates, stripe-payments

I am trying to embed Stripe in custom profile app and using django-registration package for registering users. I need to get users registered and then generate a Stripe ID for new users but getting the error below:

```
OperationalError at /accounts/login/
no such table: profiles_userstripe
```

My complete code for Profile app model is given below:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in

from dailydeals.stripe_info import secret_key, publish_key
import stripe
stripe.api_key = secret_key


class UserStripe(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    stripe_id = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='000-000-0000')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username


def CreateStripeID(sender, user, request, **kwargs):

    new_id, created = UserStripe.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
    if created:
    # add users email to stripe and then set stripe id to model
        stripe_cust = stripe.Customer.create(email=user.email, description = 'Customer %s was created' \   
       %(user.username))
        print stripe_cust.id
        new_id.stripe_id = stripe_cust.id
        new_id.save()
    else:
        print "Stripe has been created %s " %new_id
       #print "user logged in %s, %s, %s" %(sender, user, request)

user_logged_in.connect(CreateStripeID)
```

Please advise.

Comment: Have you tried creating a migration and running it to create the table?

Comment: Yes I did...infact as I am in dev mode so I deleted db couple of times to make sure Sqlite isn't creating an empty db. Also I am using built-in templates for django-registration app. When I use login it works fine...when I logout it shows the error I posted above.

Comment: What is the full traceback? What does your migration file for the profiles all look like? What happens when you run `./manage.py showmigrations profiles`?

Comment: I am not sure if its command to be used with 1.6.8...not working on Windows.

Comment: You're right, Django migrations (instead of South) were added in Django 1.7, and the `showmigrations` command was added in 1.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's kind of weird. But when I followed "[No Such Table error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103244/no-such-table-error)" and tested DB it was still empty. So this time I deleted DB but also migrations. Problem is fixed and its just working fine.