# Error 1: 'no such table: BrailleBin'.'

Tags: .net, sqlite, uwp

I'm programming an UWP that use a DB.  I'm using SQlite to connect my app to the DB. My DB is too simple: it has 1 table("BrailleBin") with 2 columns("bin" and "id"). I'm using the library of .NET: Microsoft.Data.Sqlite;

The problem is that when I deploy the app, this show me an error: Error 1: 'no such table: BrailleBin'.'.

This is my code to connect with the DB:

```
using (var transaccion = db.BeginTransaction())
{
    var Comando = db.CreateCommand();
    Comando.Transaction = transaccion;
    for(int j=0; j < texto.ToString().Length; j++)
    {
        int n = texto[j];
        Comando.CommandText = "SELECT BrailleBin.bin FROM BrailleBin WHERE BrailleBin.id = " + n;
        var datos = Comando.ExecuteReader();
        datos.Read();
        textoConcatenado = textoConcatenado + datos.GetString(0);
    }
    transaccion.Commit();
}
```

[image: This is my DB in Visual Studio]

[image: This is my DB]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No Such Table error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103244/no-such-table-error)

Comment: Show the code that creates the database and the table.

Comment: I don't create the DB inside the logic of the app. I created it in SQLite Browser and copied it to the local folder of the app

Answer (score 1):

> Error 1: 'no such table: BrailleBin'.'

This is because there is no table named "BrailleBin"  existed on the database you connected. In a uwp app with using sqlite, if you didn't align the path for the database, at default it will try to find the database on the app's [local folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.ApplicationData#Windows_Storage_ApplicationData_LocalFolder), if the database is not existed, it will create a new blank database silently with the database name you aligned for the database connection.

> I don't create the DB inside the logic of the app. I created it in SQLite Browser and copied it to the local folder of the app

Since you didn't create the db by code, the most possible reason is that the app doesn't find the database you aligned to connect,  so it create a new blank database and there is no "BrailleBin" table.

Since you didn't provide your database name  here and you didn't show the code line for creating the `db`, so please check if the database name is same when creating the database connection with the database you copied to the local folder. If they are the same, please check if you copy the database to the right place. The default local folder path is `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Packages\{your app package name}\LocalState`.