# how to open sqlite database in react native

Tags: sqlite, react-native

im using sqlite database in my react native project 
i made  app_db database that contain users table ,

> and the path of database : 
>   /home/dina/AppointmentApp/android/app/src/main/assets/app_db

now i want to access to the users table in my project and execute some queries like select , update, insert ...etc

here is the code of open connection

```
  var db = SQLite.openDatabase({name : "app_db", createFromLocation : "~app_db"});


  db.transaction((tx)=>{

 tx.executeSql("select * from users",(tx,results) => {
  });

    });
```

i dont know if this query is correct or not 
it is return in console

> -OPEN database: app_db
>   -{message: "no such table: users (Sqlite code 1): , while comp…m users, (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)", code: 0}

Comment: I am in a somewhat problem that you can help me resolve, how did you create the database in the react native application folder ? @Dina Omari. I created a database but its get created at "/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0746958E-03AA-4A38-A208-2CD36B1A484E/data/Containers/Data/Application/7BE0AC9A-BD41-44DE-A2ED-31EA58CEB22E/Library/LocalDatabase/Reactoffline.db"

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but as per the error code: your database does not have the table "users".

If you are certain that it does, then perhaps the path you point to is wrong, and the database is created automatically (without a users table).

See here for a similar problem: [No Such Table error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103244/no-such-table-error)