# Insert Single quotes in SQLite

Tags: visual-studio, sqlite, insert

I'm trying to add the following text to my database: `Zeeland '96`

But the single quote is giving me errors.

It should look like this:

```
INSERT INTO Department (Code, Name, CountryID) VALUES ('ZE', 'Zeeland '96', 1)
```

As you can see, at this moment is one quote missing, how can I get rid of this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603572/how-to-properly-escape-a-single-quote-for-a-sqlite-database?rq=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you can see [HERE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) you need to escape it by using two single quotes in a row. Try:

```
INSERT INTO Department (Code, Name, CountryID) VALUES ('ZE', 'Zeeland ''96', 1)
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're using .NET Library, you can use the SQLiteParameter types to build an SQL command string.

Answer (score -1):

```
INSERT INTO Department (Code, Name, CountryID) VALUES ('ZE', 'Zeeland ''96', 1)
```