# How to keep " ' (Single quote)" in sqlite3 with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

My environment:

- Python 3.6.5
- SQLite 3.28.0

I am struggling to save a single quote in the sqlite3 database.

```
import sqlite3


class Database:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dbpath = 'db.sqlite3'
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(self.dbpath)
        self.c = self.conn.cursor()


db = Database()


def update_comment(name, comment='null'):
    db.c.execute('update twitter_users set comment = ? where name = ?', (comment, name))
    db.conn.commit()


update_comment('Jikkenndesu', "How's day?")
```

But if I execute `select * from twitter_users;`, it output `Jikkenndesu|Hows day?`. The single quote is banished.

How can I solve this issue?
`

Comment: Not getting this issue in my setup. Can you provide the schema for `twitter_users`?

Comment: Are those of any help here? 
1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200461/insert-single-quotes-in-sqlite?lq=1
2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603572/escape-single-quote-character-for-use-in-an-sqlite-query

Comment: Thank you, guys. But it seems not to be a help for me.

Comment: The sqlite3 file is here.https://www.dropbox.com/s/xtvmrjmg5tkgtb7/db.sqlite3?dl=0

Comment: it storing fine in db, it is str in terminal so you dont need to worry about htis

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue with code blow:

```
import sqlite3


class Database:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dbpath = 'db.sqlite3'
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(self.dbpath)
        self.c = self.conn.cursor()


db = Database()


def update_comment(name, comment='null'):
    db.c.execute("""update twitter_users set comment = ? where name = ?""", (comment, name))
    db.conn.commit()


update_comment('Jikkenndesu', "It's a bad day today, and I will go to Phillip's")
```