# cordova-sqlite-porter importSqlToDb sql injection

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova, cordova-plugins, sql-insert

I use the sqlite-porter with importSqlToDb(). But now I have problem with single quota or with back slash in the string. Is there a solution for that?

Becouse I have to write the sql query like this : "INSERT INTO Artist(Id,Title) VALUES ('1','Fred's ball \ shoe');"; and can not use parameter.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes in values should be escaped by using double single quotes in SQLite ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603572/how-to-properly-escape-a-single-quote-for-a-sqlite-database)). Backslashes are fine as literals. So you should use:

```
 "INSERT INTO Artist(Id,Title) VALUES ('1','Fred''s ball \ shoe');";
```

The [example project](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-sqlite-porter-example) for [cordova-sqlite-porter](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-sqlite-porter-example) contains a [complex example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dpa99c/cordova-sqlite-porter-example/master/www/sql/complex_dump.sql) which illustrates use of both single quotes and backslashes in value strings, for example:

```
INSERT INTO [Artist] ([ArtistId], [Name]) VALUES (88, 'Guns N'' Roses');

INSERT INTO [Track] ([TrackId], [Name], [AlbumId], [MediaTypeId], [GenreId], [Composer], [Milliseconds], [Bytes], [UnitPrice]) VALUES (3435, 'Cavalleria Rusticana \ Act \ Intermezzo Sinfonico', 302, 2, 24, 'Pietro Mascagni', 243436, 4001276, 0.99);
```

Comment: Hi, yes that is right! But I get this string from a service, wich brings it like ' Guns N' Roses'. So if I create the sql query with parameters, there will be no problem, becouse it will handle the single quotes. I can't use regex to replace the single quote, becouse this string which i receive from the service can contain html tags like "<div>bla bla <a href="#">this</a></div>". Is there a function which edit this string like a I would insert with params?

Comment: Regardless of how you do it, you will need to double escape the single quotes in values. You can use a regex, even if they are contained in HTML. It just needs to ignore single quotes in attributes. Something like this:  `/>(?:[^<']*(')[^<']*)*</g`