# how to escape single quote in sqlite query in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

My sqlite query got error due to value of CharSequence s. In this value i have single quote(people's) which is not running properly. the query is running correct with double time single quote(people''s).

and code error is like below

```
07-27 14:48:32.042: E/SQLiteLog(28325): (1) near "s": syntax error
07-27 14:48:32.052: E/AndroidRuntime(28325): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-27 14:48:32.052: E/AndroidRuntime(28325): Process:
com.compare.WorldAtlasPro, PID: 28325 07-27 14:48:32.052:
E/AndroidRuntime(28325): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near
"s": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT Name FROM
country_info WHERE Name LIKE '%People's Republic of China%' AND Name
NOT LIKE ''AND Name NOT LIKE ''  AND Name NOT LIKE ''AND Name NOT LIKE
'' order by Name ASC
```

Here below of my code.

```
    country2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            ArrayList<String> mArrayList=new ArrayList<String>();

            Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT Name FROM country_info WHERE Name LIKE '%"+s+"%' AND" +" Name NOT LIKE'"+country1.getText().toString()+"'AND Name NOT LIKE'"+country3.getText().toString()+"' " +" AND Name NOT LIKE'"+country4.getText().toString()+"'AND Name NOT LIKE'"+country5.getText().toString()+"' " +    "order by Name ASC", null);

            while(c.moveToNext()){

                mArrayList.add(c.getString(0));

            }

            country2.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(mCtx,mArrayList));


        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: i tried that solution but i got error as " The method replaceAll(String, String) is undefined for the type CharSequence "

Comment: Why don't you use **bound parameters**, instead?

Comment: Leave space in front of `AND` in two places @YuvaanChauhan

Comment: Not solved  @arshak

Comment: Your `country1.getText().toString()` , `country3.getText().toString()` , `country4.getText().toString()` ,  `country5.getText().toString()` is returning `empty` @YuvaanChauhan

Comment: That question has more than one answer.

Comment: @Arshak return empty is not problem in query but problem is i want to change value from single comma (people's) to  double time single comma (people''s)

Comment: @YuvaanChauhan Try to find out whether the arguments passed into the query contains `special character`, & if it contain's special character then use escape sequence... in your case, append it with another `'` .  Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/603579/5744335)..

Comment: Done as 
**String sy =s.toString().replaceAll("'","''");
Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT Name FROM country_info WHERE Name LIKE '%"+sy+"%' AND" +" Name NOT LIKE'"+country1.getText().toString().replaceAll("'","''")+"'AND Name NOT LIKE '"+country3.getText().toString().replaceAll("'","''")+"' " +" AND Name NOT LIKE "+country4.getText().toString().replaceAll("'","''")+"'AND Name NOT LIKE '"+country5.getText().toString().replaceAll("'","''")+"' " +"order by Name ASC", null);**