# Escaping single quotes for sqlite3 from the shell

Tags: shell, sqlite, escaping, single-quotes

I am trying to add single quotes into my DB but when i double up the single quotes in the DB i dont get a single quote to appear? Reading this document: 
[How to properly escape a single quote for a SQLite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603572/how-to-properly-escape-a-single-quote-for-a-sqlite-database)

I was not able to successfully add the single quote. I am logged in via SSH so i am not sure if this is the cause? Perhaps there is something else involved to accomplish this?

My Insert command:

```
sqlite3 /db.sql 'insert into `custqueue` values ("2", "take''that", "2")';
```

My select (Read) response:

```
2|takethat|2
```

I dont have my single quote in takethat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash` does not allow a single quote between single quotes; any single quote ends the quoted string. So to get a single quote into SQL, you have to use a single quote to end the string, write an escaped quote, and then use another single quote to start the remaining quoted string:

```
sqlite3 dbfile 'INSERT INTO tab VALUES(2, "take'\''that", 2);'
```

Comment: Currently restoring one my images to boot from but once done will give this a go! Thanks, much appreciated

Comment: Worked a charm! Thanks