# How to access sqlite3-database from function in PHP

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm new to SQLite and currently trying to use it for a project.
I've created a function that inserts a new row if one with the given name doesn't exist already.
However, I can't seem to access the database-variable from inside the function. Nothing is happening.

My first try throws an error:

```
$db = new SQLite3("name.db");
$db->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS warehouses (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(255), adjacent_l INTEGER DEFAULT null, adjacent_r INTEGER DEFAULT null, chem_a INTEGER DEFAULT 0, chem_b INTEGER DEFAULT 0, chem_c INTEGER DEFAULT 0, cap INTEGER)");

function newWH($name, $cap)
{
    $letResult = $db->query("SELECT * FROM warehouses WHERE name = " . $name);
    $letArray = (array) $letResult;
    if (empty($letArray)) {
        $db->query("INSERT INTO warehouses (name, cap) VALUES (" . $name . ", " . $cap . ")");
    }
}

newWH("wh1", 10);
```

I tried passing the db-variable as a parameter. The website no longer throws an error, but no inserts are happening. (And yes, I've tried it without the if-clause :-)

```
$db = new SQLite3("name.db");
$db->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS warehouses (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(255), adjacent_l INTEGER DEFAULT null, adjacent_r INTEGER DEFAULT null, chem_a INTEGER DEFAULT 0, chem_b INTEGER DEFAULT 0, chem_c INTEGER DEFAULT 0, cap INTEGER)");

function newWH($name, $cap, $letDb)
{
    $letResult = $letDb->query("SELECT * FROM warehouses WHERE name = " . $name);
    $letArray = (array) $letResult;
    if (empty($letArray)) {
        $letDb->query("INSERT INTO warehouses (name, cap) VALUES (" . $name . ", " . $cap . ")");
    }
}

newWH("wh1", 10, $db);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It's better to declare your `$db` as **global** in the function
2. your `name` column is VARCHAR so you have to surround its value with quotes in your SQL instructions

Thus:

```
$db = new SQLite3("name.db");
$db->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS warehouses (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(255), adjacent_l INTEGER DEFAULT null, adjacent_r INTEGER DEFAULT null, chem_a INTEGER DEFAULT 0, chem_b INTEGER DEFAULT 0, chem_c INTEGER DEFAULT 0, cap INTEGER)");

function newWH($name, $cap)
{
    global $db;
    $letResult = $db->query("SELECT * FROM warehouses WHERE name = '$name'");
    $letArray = (array) $letResult;
    if (empty($letArray)) {
        $db->query("INSERT INTO warehouses (name, cap) VALUES ('$name', $cap)");
    }
}

newWH("wh1", 10);
```

3. use parametrized queries and bind variables to avoid SQL injections. [THIS](https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2012/php-pdo-sqlite3-example/)  is a good start to learn how to use PDO with SQLite
4. If you don't care about 3, then you should at least [escape quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603572/escape-single-quote-character-for-use-in-an-sqlite-query) characters in `name`

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. 
1 and 2 did the job
I am using SQLite for dummy purposes, so I didn't want to bring PDO into the project, but I might