# SQL Insert with '

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

i am trying to insert a `String` with sql into my database.
This String may contain a " **'** ".

When i now try to insert it into my database i get this error:

> [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near " characters after the **'** ": syntax error)

Function call:

```
  Main.execute("INSERT INTO Projektname(projektname) VALUES('" + txtFd_name.getText() + "');");
```

Main.execute:

```
public static void execute(String query){
        class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:D:\\user\\eclipse-workspace\\S2LDB.db");
        Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
        stat.execute(query);
}
```

i tried it with `org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava()`

Comment: With a `PreparedStatement` you can use [`setString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString(int,%20java.lang.String)), and you will be protected from SQL injection. You should not be trying to glue input directly into your query.

Comment: @khelwood `escapeJava()` is unnecessary then?

Comment: Yes, `escapeJava` is unnecessary if  you're using statement parameters properly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should absolutely be using a prepared statement here, which would handle the problem of properly escaping a single quote when doing an insert.  Something like this:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO Projektname(projektname) VALUES(?)";

try (Connection conn = this.connect();
    PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        pstmt.setString(1, txtFd_name.getText());
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

If you must continue with your current approach, then you might able to try manually doubling up all the single quotes.  So this *might* make your current insert work:

```
String name = txtFd_name.getText().replaceAll("'", "''");
String sql = "INSERT INTO Projektname(projektname) VALUES('" + name + "');");
Main.execute(sql);
```

But, I don't recommend doing this, because this could backfire depending on how many single quotes you already have.  Using a prepared statement is the better way to go.

Comment: You're missing `pstmt.executeUpdate();`

Comment: @Codo It's a miracle we don't all make more mistakes here than we already do :-)

Comment: thy, i will use a `preparedStatement` now

Answer (score 0):

you should escape the ' with a double single quote, before using this value in your string composition

```
txtFd_name.getText()
```

assign the value to a string variable and then replace ' with '' ( twice ' ) and it should work.

see here for an example: [Escape single quote character for use in an SQLite query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603572/escape-single-quote-character-for-use-in-an-sqlite-query)

if it was sql server and .NET I would suggest to use query or command parameters not sure about java and sqlite

Answer (score 0):

I fix this writing two ' insted of one.
Something like this:

```
Main.execute("INSERT INTO Projektname(projektname) VALUES(''" + txtFd_name.getText() + "'');");
```