# Escaping chacters. OperationalError: syntax error

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, python-3.6

I have a SQLite database with a single table called `min` that has a single column (TEXT) called `name` and I want to use the following SQLite command to insert values.

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO min VALUES ('{}');
```

The problem is that when the name has a single quote, I get the error in the question's title.

Here's a minimal example using `pandas` to visualize the table.

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

db = "question.db"

#helper functions
def run_query(q):
    with sqlite3.connect(db) as conn:
        return pd.read_sql(q, conn)

def run_command(c):
    with sqlite3.connect(db) as conn:
        conn.isolation_level = None
        conn.execute(c)

create_table =\
"""
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS min(
    name TEXT
);
"""
run_command(create_table)

display(run_query("SELECT * FROM min;"))

insert_command = """\
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO min
VALUES ('{}');
"""

run_command(insert_command.format("Jules"))

display(run_query("SELECT * FROM min;"))

print(insert_command.format("O'Brien")) #visualize the command string
```

Prints

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO min
VALUES ('O'Brien');
```

And running the command itself

```
run_command(insert_command.format("O'Brien"))
```

Yields:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-e374715cfbec> in <module>()
      1 print(insert_command.format("O'Brien"))
----> 2 run_command(insert_command.format("O'Brien"))

<ipython-input-3-0c8eb910c0ac> in run_command(c)
      7     with sqlite3.connect(db) as conn:
      8         conn.isolation_level = None
----> 9         conn.execute(c)

OperationalError: near "Brien": syntax error
```

Escaping the single quote does not help:

```
print(insert_command.format("O\\'Brien"))
```

Prints

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO min
VALUES ('O\'Brien');
```

And the same error happens with

```
run_command(insert_command.format("O\\'Brien"))
```

How can I escape this quote or otherwise solve this problem? I do not wish to replace the single quotes with doubles quotes as that would only shift the problem.

Comment: Take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603572/escape-single-quote-character-for-use-in-an-sqlite-query)

Comment: @teh_raab Thanks. That solves it.

Comment: Don't try to insert arbitrary values into a query at runtime. Use placeholders in the query and bind the values to them. See the python sqlite bindings documentation for numerous examples.

Comment: @Shawn Thank you. I'm not doing that in my script, this was just a minimal example.